# An IF Statement Is Changing An Array Element In A Function

Tags: c, arrays, function, if-statement

When my program runs, the IF ( ch[0] == 'P') actually puts the value 'P' into ch[0]. Any ideas what is happening here? The output is: "Array is Pyz"

```
char *try1(char ch[]);

int main()
{
  char ch[] = { 'x','y','z' }, *ch1;
  ch1=try1(ch); 
  printf("\nArray is %s\n",ch1);
  return 0;
}

char *try1 (char ch[])
{
  if (ch[0]=='P')
  {
    ch[1]='Q';
  }

  return ch;
}
```

Comment: Are you sure you have a `==` and not a `=`?

Comment: Thank you BJ Myers.  You are right.  Sorry, I'd tried to be very careful before I posted this but I missed that.  I'll be more thorough in the future.

Comment: You should look into [proper C formatting](//prohackr112.tk/r/proper-c-formatting). Or learn how to [thoroughly obfuscate your code](//prohackr112.tk/r/proper-c-obfuscation).

Comment: A strong case for always placing the literal on the left side of an equality expression,  so the compiler catches the problem rather than you having to spend your time and effort debugging the program.

Comment: the array `ch[]` is not NUL terminated, so the call to `printf()` will result in garbage being output after the actual 3 bytes in the array until a NUL byte is encountered.   This is undefined behavior and can lead to a seg fault event.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to interpret ch as a string, you should terminate the array with '/0'.  Replace

```c
char ch[] = { 'x','y','z'}
```

with

```c
char ch[] = { 'x','y','z', '\0' }
```

and the output becomes "Array is xyz."

For more information, read https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null-terminated_string